# If one uses an AI model licensed under CC-BY-SA in a program, must the program be licensed under CC-BY-SA?

Tags: derivative-works, cc-by-sa, artificial-intelligence

If one uses an AI model licensed under CC-BY-SA (e.g., [MPT-7B-Instruct](https://www.mosaicml.com/blog/mpt-7b)) in a program, must the program by licensed under CC-BY-SA?

[creativecommons.org](https://creativecommons.org/about/cclicenses/#:%7E:text=CC%20BY%2DSA%3A%20This%20license,license%20allows%20for%20commercial%20use.) mentions:

> SA  – Adaptations must be shared under the same terms

but I don't know whether the program is considered an adaptation (aka, a derivative work) of the AI model.

Comment: See [this question on Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/91785/323).

Comment: It is clear that at least the *model* must remain CC-BY-SA and you must attribute it.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#when-is-my-use-considered-an-adaptation) and [this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-is-an-adaptation) to determine if your program is actually an adaption? You might need to consult a lawyer w.r.t. copyright law in your particular jurisdiction.